# TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED - Finding Happy Numbers

Tags: java, numbers

I did this question(return true if happpy number) on leetcode.It says Time Limit Exceeded.

A happy number is a number defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

Return True if n is a happy number, and False if not.

Example:

```
Input: 19
Output: true
Explanation: 
1^2 + 9^2 = 82
8^2 + 2^2 = 68
6^2 + 8^2 = 100
1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1
```

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isHappy(int n) {
        int sum=n;
        while(sum!=1)
        {
        sum=sum_digits(n);
        }
        return sum==1;
    }
    public int sum_digits(int num){
        int sm=0;
        while(num!=0)
        {
            int d=num%10;
            sm=sm+d*d;
            num=num/10;
        }
        return sm;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the number is not a happy number, there is a cycle formed and you'll never reach the false condition. Edit your code to include a list of all the past Happy Numbers and at each interval check if the sum is in the list. If the number has already occurred, return false

Comment: `num=num/10;` statement in your `sum_digits` method does not change its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the algorithm. First, we should say that any positive number is either "Happy" or "not Happy". The ones that are happy will give us `1` at the end anyway but the ones that are not will be stuck in a loop and will have periodic `sum_digit()`s. So if one `sum_digit()` happens twice for a given number `n` it is not Happy!

```
public static boolean isHappy(int n) {
    int sum=n;
    List<Integer> history=new ArrayList<>();//for holding a list of numbers that have been reached
    while(sum!=1)
    {
        history.add(sum);
        sum=sum_digits(sum);
        if(history.contains(sum)){//if one the numbers in history repeats it will loop forever though n is not Happy
            return false;
        }
    }
    return sum==1;
}
public static int sum_digits(int num){
    int sm=0;
    int n=num;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        int d=n%10;
        sm=sm+d*d;
        n=n/10;
    }
    return sm;
}
```

Now you can use it to find all Happy numbers less that 1000 (or any number you wish):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(isHappy(999999));
  for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (isHappy(i))System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```